# Python BeautifulSoup Empty Rows in CSV File

Tags: python, mysql, sql, excel, csv

I am working on a scraper to pull street names and zip codes from a site and all of that is working great and it builds a CSV file just fine for me. But when I open the CSV file in Excel the file will have a blank row than a row with a street name with the zip code in the next column just like I want. But next I have a blank row than a row with a street name and zip code beside it. And this just continues on all the way through the file which gives me a row with a street name and zip codes in row then the word none in the next row when imported into the PHPMyAdmin database. I want to get rid of the blank rows. Here is my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv 

import urllib2

url="http://www.conakat.com/states/ohio/cities/defiance/road_maps/"

page=urllib2.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

f = csv.writer(open("Defiance Steets1.csv", "w"))
f.writerow(["Street", "Zipcode"]) # Write column headers as the first line

links = soup.find_all('a')

for link in links:
    i = link.find_next_sibling('i')
    if getattr(i, 'name', None):
        a, i = link.string, i.string[1:-1] 
        f.writerow([a, i])
```

Comment: Do you have an extra blank row after your column headers, before the first entry?

Comment: Yes I did the answer below helped me solve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me (I added `lineterminator ="\n"`):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import csv 

import urllib2

url="http://www.conakat.com/states/ohio/cities/defiance/road_maps/"

page=urllib2.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())


f = csv.writer(open("Defiance Steets1.csv", "w"), lineterminator ="\n")
f.writerow(["Street", "Zipcode"]) # Write column headers as the first line

#print soup.
links = soup.findAll('a')

for link in links:
    #i = link.find_next_sibling('i')
    i = link.findNextSibling('i')
    if getattr(i, 'name', None):
        a, i = link.string, i.string[1:-1] 
        print [a,i]
        f.writerow([a, i])
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me... thanks
if you have the writer and open in different lines,
put it as a param in the writer function...